# Rename the google-direction tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

To my understanding, the [google-direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-direction) tag was created to tag questions related to the [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start).

Therefore it should be renamed to `google-directions-api` which would be consistent with other Google API products as listed below:

- [google-places-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-places-api)
- [google-roads-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-roads-api)
- [google-maps-api-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-3)