# Rename the google-direction-api tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I had made a request to rename the [google-direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-direction) tag [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398106/rename-the-google-direction-tag) and it was renamed to [google-direction-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-direction-api) instead of [google-directions-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-directions-api) (with an "**s**"; see my comment on the original request).

Comment: I assume Cody has still nightmares from that [giant-S](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/158100) and tries to avoid it.

Comment: Although this isn't about pluralization but about correctly naming a tag.

Comment: @rene I heard that references to the giant-S were "not nice" and should not be used :)

Comment: Joking aside, I partially agree with @MrUpsidown - official name is [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start). That said, searching for [singular](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=direction-api) yields >2x times more results than for [plural](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=directions-api), so it is probably a win. Also, it would be more beneficial if we took effort to [create a tag wiki and excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-direction-api/info) for the tag that are missing for almost 9 years.

Comment: Did I screw that up? Hmm, sorry. I don't know if it was a typo, or there was an existing tag without the "s" that got automatically selected when I went to merge. Either way...fixed now. Closing this as a dupe. Sorry I didn't get your comment on that question, or I would have fixed it there without your needing to go through the effort of re-asking. My on-site inbox often overflows with 500+ items, and I just can't reasonably get to them all, especially since clicking it once causes all "new" status to be cleared.

Comment: @CodyGray - what would you think about creating a standalone A&A community-wiki style that can be used as a target for all renaming / synonymizing / merging requests instead of each user who wants this posting a question and hoping that you will notice (which, given your workload, you do an amazing job of)? You can then kick back at the start / end of a busy day, have a cup of coffee and look through the updates on the subject matter (just pitching an idea)

Comment: @Oleg Problem is, on everything but externally-verifiable renames (e.g., those needed to be consistent with actual product/company names), mods need the community to weigh in, preferably other tag experts. This is done both by comments but even more importantly by voting. If you just have a big community wiki, it puts all the decision for what to do on moderators, and we often don't know. We don't want the sole responsibility.

Comment: @CodyGray - yeah, that might be a problem... To clarify, though, I meant having a Q&A (maybe even not a wiki) where answers are requests for renaming / merging, etc. And the question can contain some guidance, links to discussions and FAQs of when / how to request, etc. Maybe even split by request type to avoid bloat - what do you think?

Comment: @Oleg I'm just not convinced that a single massive Q&A (where each answer is a request) would be any improvement over individual requests (where each question is a request). If anything, it would be worse, because when a question is the request, answers can be posted indicating agreement or disagreement. When an answer is the request, all you have are comments, and comments are terrible. :-) I can filter retag requests easily, even when posted as questions, as long as the correct tag(s) are used, and I have tag filters set up to do this.

Comment: @CodyGray thanks for your time.

Comment: @CodyGray - well, alas! I get your point - given that separate requests are probably the best option you have for now... Did not think about a possibility of agreement / disagreement answers.Thank you for monitoring the requests!

Comment: You're welcome, everyone. I appreciate all the suggestions and thoughts being put into how to possibly improve workflow, even if I ultimately disagree. We're all smarter by working together. For what it's worth, I'm a big fan of opening pluralization bugs (and, really, all sorts of grammar nitpicks). I was the one who used to give the team nightmares any time they added features, because I was going to come the next day and nitpick about the grammar. While the meme is reasonably deprecated by the passage of time, I still don't agree with Tim that it violates the Code of Conduct in any way.