# Remove / merge google-maps-direction-api tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The [google-maps-direction-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-direction-api) is a synonym of the [google-directions-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-directions-api) tag for questions about the [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start).

I suggest we merge it to [google-directions-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-directions-api)

Related request: [Rename the google-direction tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398106/rename-the-google-direction-tag)

Comment: The [[tag:google-maps-direction-api]] does not appear to be a synonym of the [[tag:google-directions-api]] tag. Are you proposing that it be *created* as one? What is the difference between these two tags? This request isn't entirely clear to me.

Comment: @CodyGray - while I am not one to assess the intention (still: you probably interpreted correctly, "synonym" here is not used in a strict sense of a tag synonym), so on your second question: Google Maps Platform has a [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start) and a [Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial), but no "Google Maps Direction API" which seems a bit confusing. Also the wiki throws [`DirectionsService`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) object in the mix...

Comment: ...Note to readers: if we do this, we need to ensure the [target tag has a wiki and excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-directions-api/info)

Comment: @OlegValter I have created the tag wiki. It is under review since yesterday.

Comment: @CodyGray There is indeed the Directions API, as a **web service**, and the Directions Service, as part of the **Maps Javascript API**. In the end, it's the same API but with different ways to access it. IMO, we can keep only one tag (google-directions-api). If we would keep separate tags for the web service and the service as part of the JS API, then we would be missing other tags for other APIs that have the same structure (Places API, Geocoding API, etc.).

Comment: @MrUpsidown - re:wiki - thank you, let's hope it will be approved soon (alas, I have 2K to go to vote for approval). This starts to look like a fully-fledged Google APIs retagging project, btw (maybe with a centralized Q&A, I am not sure about that, though?)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, Google Maps seems to have two distinct APIs, which is 1. The [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start) and 2. The [Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial). Given that the [google-maps-direction-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-direction-api) was being used solely for the [google-direction-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-direction-api), I added it as a synonym, that is:

[google-maps-direction-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-direction-api) (× 134) → [google-directions-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-directions-api) (× 335)

I'll merge the two tags after a couple of weeks, just in case there's some issue with the synonym, and we'd have to revert it.